# How to build a PPA package on Launchpad from a git repository with submodules?

Tags: ppa, git, launchpad

I'm currently trying to revive our project PPA since we started using Git submodules two months ago and import to Bazaar stopped working since it doesn't support submodules. So I removed bzr and successfully imported our repository to Launchpad as Git.

Sadly, after I attempted to build it with newly created recipe build is failing since repository isn't cloned recursively and submodules still not present. I can't find any help in Launchpad own documentation and while its support feature called "nesting" it doesn't seem to be a good choice to workaround recursive clone.

How can I make Launchpad clone repository recursively before the build?

Comment: One possible workaround is to use [nesting](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes#Nesting) in your recipe.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/git-build-recipe/+bug/1733603/comments/8 here I put description of the workaround

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to do it at the moment, but this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/git-build-recipe/+bug/1733603) and should be fixable.  (Feel free to dig into the [git-build-recipe source](https://code.launchpad.net/git-build-recipe) and propose a fix if you're in a rush.)

---

### Workaround

However, there is a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/git-build-recipe/+bug/1733603/comments/8). First, import all the submodules in Launchpad (you can either use different projects, or use different git repositories in the same project).

### An example

For example, [here](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+recipe/marker-daily) is the source package recipe for [Marker](https://github.com/fabiocolacio/Marker). Marker needs the submodule `scidown`, which needs `charter`, which needs `tinyexpr`.

First, I registered these projects at Launchpad, and mirrored the GitHub repos to `lp:scidown`, `lp:charter`, and `lp:tinyexpr`.

The source recipe is,

```
# git-build-recipe format 0.4 deb-version 2020.04.04-0~{revtime}
lp:marker master
nest scidown lp:scidown src/scidown a7b7f063de4f272ef0ec12d00b98470888e8cb32
nest charter lp:charter src/scidown/src/charter a25dee1214ea9ba5882325066555cb813efbb489
nest tinyexpr lp:tinyexpr src/scidown/src/charter/src/tinyexpr 9476568b69de4c384903f1d5f255907b92592f45
```

The second line tells launchpad to use the `master` branch of lp:marker.

The third line copies the whole contents of lp:scidown (in the commit `a7b7f063de4f272ef0ec12d00b98470888e8cb32`) into `src/scidown` of the Marker repository.

The fourth line copies the whole contents of lp:charter (of the commit `a25dee1214ea9ba5882325066555cb813efbb489`) into `src/scidown/src/charter` of the Marker repository (charter is a submodule required to build scidown).

The third line copies the whole contents of lp:tinyexpr (of the commit `9476568b69de4c384903f1d5f255907b92592f45`) into `src/scidown/src/charter/src/tinyexpr` of the Marker repository (tinyexpr is a submodule required to build charter).